# Not able to access EC2 custom port from remote machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, tcp-port

I have hosted web application (developed in PHP) on Amazon EC2 micro instance. As per default setting, i can access 80, 22, 443 and 3306 ports from remote locations  means from Home(terminal window) using telnet command.

I want to open another custom TCP port XXXXX. I have added that port in Security Group. when i am trying to connect that port through telnet command it is always show "Connection refused".

I have been trying to solve this issue for 3 days but could not get successful solution.

Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a port in security group (inbound) ensures that the port can be accessed from outside. Please check following

1. Is the port open for anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) or for a custom IP. If for custom IP, please check the IP of your machine (search 'what is my ip' on google).
2. Is there any application listening on the port on EC2 machine.